# This "Insertion sort" code in "Atom" ide using "C++" gives ouput properly but in "Intellij Idea" using "java" the same code gives index out of bound

Tags: java, intellij-idea, while-loop, atom-editor

```
package JavaTest1;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class javatest1000 {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = sc.nextInt();
    int[] arr = new int[n];

    //taking input of the array
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      arr[i] = sc.nextInt();
    }

    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
      int current = arr[i];
      int j = i - 1;
      while (arr[j] > current && j >= 0) {
        arr[j + 1] = arr[j];
        j--;
      }

      arr[j + 1] = current;
    }

    //printing output of the sorted array
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      System.out.print(arr[i] + " ");

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Format your question properly. Include the input and the output in the question. There is a reason why SO tells you that your question is code only. We expect some research to to be done by the author of question. Saves the time for both of us.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, Java is throwing an exception because there really is a bug in your Java code.  It is (frankly) implausible that you are seeing the results of a bug in either Intellij or in Java.

(I'm not going to try to work out what the bug is.  This is your homework.  If you want some hints on how to proceed, read [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).)

So ... if the C++ version works, there are two possibilities:

- Your Java implementation is not a correct translation of the C++ implementation.
- The C++ version also has bugs, but they are not manifesting as a crash.

My understanding is that *typical* C++ implementations do not implement strict bounds checking on subscripting operations.  So you can often refer to a value beyond the end (or before the start) of an array without triggering an error.  The behavior of code that does this is *unspecified*, but there is a chance that the application will work ... on some platforms, for some inputs, etc ... despite the bug.

Putting it another way, "it doesn't crash" doesn't mean "it is correct".  Not for C++, or Java, or *any* programming language.